# How to make a text section appear only in the most recent post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a certain text part appear at the end of the most recent post in my Wordpress blog. I don't want it in all the posts, just the latest one. Is it possible?

I'm fairly good with php but kinda new to WP.

Comment: You really need to do some research first.  We can help you once you've made an attempt at coding a solution.  Start by reading up on how to get the latest post in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your WP loop, You can use the get_next_post() method. Check to see if it returns empty in an IF statement, and include your text inside the statement.

[WP Codex Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)

[Answer from Jonny Green](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208539)